# Induction adapter left stain on cooktop

Tags: cleaning, induction

My induction adapter left stain on my cooktop. I use the hob cleaner, vinegear but nothing seems to work. can anyone help. It’s new hob.

Comment: What kind of stain, could you edit and post a picture?